# postgresql vs mysql left join

Tags: mysql, postgresql

I am writing a query on a PostgreSQL db, and am not sure how to do a count of non null values after a join. In MySQL I would write:

```
select count(a.clicker_id), count(b.clicker_id) from
(select * from events where type='click') a 
left join (select * from tbl_events where type='conversion')b 
on a.clicker_id=b.clicker_id
```

Basically, trying to write the following without a subquery:

```
select  date(cl.created_at), count(cl.click_id) as clicks, count(cp.click_id) as Conversions from events_table cl
left outer join (select click_id, created_at from events_table  where type='conversion_potential')cp
on (cl.click_id=cp.click_id)
where cl."type"='click' 
and cl.placement_id in (1,2,3)
group by 1
```

Comment: You're de facto doing an inner join, due to your `b.type = conversion` clause. Double-check that your MySQL query is the one you posted.

Comment: Just deleted my answer because was wrong.

Comment: Are there really two tables, events and tbl_events as in the _RIGHT_ query?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a self join:

```
select
    count(type = 'click' or null) clicks,
    count(type = 'conversion' or null) conversions
from events_table
where campaign_id = 555
```

Comment: I do need a join, as I have some additional things in the where clause, such as clicks from under a campaign ID. I only need the conversions belonging to the selected clicks, which have the same click ID.
Conversions indeed was a type value

Comment: @AdrianBR Edited. Show your complete requirements as I still believe you don't need a self join.

Comment: I explained wrong, have some set variables that exclude or include publishers on the second instance of the table.

Answer (score 1):

Does this not work:

```
select count(a.clicker_id), count(b.clicker_id)
    from events_table as a
        left join events_table as b
        on a.clicker_id=b.clicker_id and b.type='conversion'
where a.type='click'
and campaign_id=555
```

?